# WithCount no funciona con un whereHas anidado en laravel lumen

Tags: laravel, eloquent, lumen

Estoy haciendo un siple with y un with count con las mismas condiciones, el with me lo hace perfecto pero el withCount lo  hace mal,estoy usando lumen
este es mi codigo

```
    $query =Employe::query();
$query->withCount([
            'staffEdps' => function ($staff_edp) use ($date, $rec, $stationConfig, $recertificationMonth, $stationsIdHomologateMe) {
                $staff_edp
                    ->orderBy('end_date', 'desc')->where('turn_stretch_id', $rec->turn_stretch_id)
                    ->where(function ($q) use ($date) {
                        $q->where('init_date', '>=', $date)
                            ->where('end_date', '<=', $date);
                    })
                    ->orWhere(function ($q) use ($date) {
                        $q->where('init_date', '<', $date)
                            ->where('init_date', '>=', $date);
                    })
                    ->orWhere(function ($q) use ($date) {
                        $q->where('staff_edp.init_date', '<', $date)
                            ->where('staff_edp.end_date', '>', $date);
                    })->orWhere(function ($q) use ($date) {
                        $q->where('staff_edp.init_date', '<', $date)
                            ->where('staff_edp.end_date', '>', $date);
                    })->orWhere(function ($q) use ($date) {
                        $q->where('staff_edp.init_date', '<=', $date)
                            ->whereNull('staff_edp.end_date');
                    })->where('configuration_station_id', $rec->configuration_station_id);
                $staff_edp->whereHas('datesActive', function ($datestaff) use ($date) {
                    $datestaff->where(function ($q) use ($date) {
                        $q->where('init_date', '>=', $date)
                            ->where('end_date', '<=', $date);
                    })
                        ->orWhere(function ($q) use ($date) {
                            $q->where('init_date', '<', $date)
                                ->where('init_date', '>=', $date);
                        })
                        ->orWhere(function ($q) use ($date) {
                            $q->where('init_date', '<', $date)
                                ->where('end_date', '>', $date);
                        })->orWhere(function ($q) use ($date) {
                            $q->where('init_date', '<', $date)
                                ->where('end_date', '>', $date);
                        })->orWhere(function ($q) use ($date) {
                            $q->where('init_date', '<=', $date)
                                ->whereNull('end_date');
                        });
                });
            }
        ]);
        $query->with('staffEdps', function ($staff_edp) use ($rec, $date) {
            $staff_edp
                ->where('turn_stretch_id', $rec->turn_stretch_id)
                ->orderBy('end_date', 'desc')
                ->where(function ($q) use ($date) {
                    $q->where('init_date', '>=', $date)
                        ->where('end_date', '<=', $date);
                })
                ->orWhere(function ($q) use ($date) {
                    $q->where('init_date', '<', $date)
                        ->where('init_date', '>=', $date);
                })
                ->orWhere(function ($q) use ($date) {
                    $q->where('staff_edp.init_date', '<', $date)
                        ->where('staff_edp.end_date', '>', $date);
                })->orWhere(function ($q) use ($date) {
                    $q->where('staff_edp.init_date', '<', $date)
                        ->where('staff_edp.end_date', '>', $date);
                })->orWhere(function ($q) use ($date) {
                    $q->where('staff_edp.init_date', '<=', $date)
                        ->whereNull('staff_edp.end_date');
                });
            $staff_edp->withAndWhereHas('datesActive', function ($datestaff) use ($date) {
                $datestaff->where(function ($q) use ($date) {
                    $q->where('init_date', '>=', $date)
                        ->where('end_date', '<=', $date);
                })
                    ->orWhere(function ($q) use ($date) {
                        $q->where('init_date', '<', $date)
                            ->where('init_date', '>=', $date);
                    })
                    ->orWhere(function ($q) use ($date) {
                        $q->where('init_date', '<', $date)
                            ->where('end_date', '>', $date);
                    })->orWhere(function ($q) use ($date) {
                        $q->where('init_date', '<', $date)
                            ->where('end_date', '>', $date);
                    })->orWhere(function ($q) use ($date) {
                        $q->where('init_date', '<=', $date)
                            ->whereNull('end_date');
                    });
            })->where('configuration_station_id', $rec->configuration_station_id);
        });
        $query->orderBy('staff_edps_count', 'desc');
```

El with y el with count estan haciendo los mismos filtros pero el withcount cuenta mas de lo que es, ya lo probe con whereHas y con WithAndWHereHas
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

L solución era mas facil de lo que parecia al pasarla a un query sql me di cuenta que las condiciones de fecha no estaban encapsuladas en un solo where como las necesitaba

```
 $staff_edp->whereHas('datesActive', function ($datestaff) use ($date) {
                $datestaff->where(function ($q) use ($date) {
                    $q->where('init_date', '>=', $date)
                        ->where('end_date', '<=', $date);
                })
                    ->orWhere(function ($q) use ($date) {
                        $q->where('init_date', '<', $date)
                            ->where('init_date', '>=', $date);
                    })
                    ->orWhere(function ($q) use ($date) {
                        $q->where('init_date', '<', $date)
                            ->where('end_date', '>', $date);
                    })->orWhere(function ($q) use ($date) {
                        $q->where('init_date', '<=', $date)
                            ->whereNull('end_date');
                    });
            });
```